# Derivate of absolute value

Tags: calculus

[The question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3m81.png)

I understand the second line but the third line i don't.
How we got 8 and how x became 1/4 ?

Comment: Think about the graph of $y=|x|$ and $y'$.

Comment: Please use MathJax to render the math formulas.

Comment: Please write out the question instead of giving a link !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving from the first to the second line, we have for $x > 1/4$,
$$\text{sgn(4x-1)} = 1.$$  For $x<1/4$,
$$\text{sgn(4x-1)} = -1.$$

So, the expression becomes $4+4 = 8$ when $x>1/4$ and $4-4 = 0$ for $x<1/4$.

Comment: Why they give you -1?

Comment: The sign is $+1$ for a positive number, and $-1$ for a negative number, by convention.

Comment: btw how did u get  sgn(4x-1) = 1 ,, where 1 come from